# Unable to get mapping to work in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, get-mapping

I have tried everything and I am unable to get springboot to map anything using @getmapping. I have previously done this in another springboot application with no issue so I confused as why I am having issues.

Here is my code for the main file.

```
package simplesoft.com.mainpage

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class MainpageApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MainpageApplication>(*args)
}
```

Here is my controller code

```
package simplesoft.com.mainpage.controller


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import org.springframework.ui.Model
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping

@Controller
class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(model: Model) : String {

        return "index"
    }

    @GetMapping("/bud")
    fun showpage(model: Model) : String {

        return "homepage"
    }
}
```

the folder structure of the project
[Here is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MobrA.png)

When I Run the application and try to go there is not mapping message in springboot and I get a 404 error when trying to access the page I have re-built the application from the spring starter website and still have the same issue.

Comment: Try adding `@RequestMapping` to the class

Comment: it made no difference, I also tried replacing getmapping with requestmapping and it also did not work.